# SQL question - how to pull date from string - error says I need to explicitly type cast

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a formula in SQL that has the tags, months, and count of each category within the month.

The table I'm pulling from contains userIDs, tag, created_date - each userID can have multiple tags.

The formula I wrote is

```
select distinct(sub."tag") AS "tag", 
month(sub."StringToDate") as "date2",
count(*) AS "quantity"
from (
    SELECT *, cast(updated_at as date) as "StringToDate"
    FROM "table1"."table2") sub
group by "tag", "date2"
```

The error I get reads

> ERROR: function month(date) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 168

Any help? I think the issue is the date is not converting correctly, so I cannot pull the month out.

Comment: Might want to add what SQL flavor you are using e.g. MSSQL, PostgreSQL, MySQL, mariaDB, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database system you use, there are some different options:

- PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle: `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM <date>)`
- also PostgreSQL: `DATE_PART('month', <date or timestamp>)`
- MS SQL Server: `MONTH(<date>);` or `DATEPART(month, <date>);`
- SQLite: `strftime('%m', <date>)`

Apparently you are not using MS SQL Server :) So maybe you have to find an option that suits your database

Comment: Thank you - the first one worked!!

Comment: That is ANSI SQL syntax, if I'm not mistaken -- so I guess it is the safest option to try anyway :) 
Glad to have helped -- feel free to mark the answer as "complete" ;)